# Emu population in Australia from 1900

Tags: data-request, environment, australia

I am looking for figures of the emu population in Australia over history.

Ideally from 1900 or even further, and especially around the time of the [Emu War](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emu_War).

Even a simple histogram would be enough.

Freely reusable data is needed.

Comment: Found this: http://i.imgur.com/V3nN6Ch.jpg

Comment: @philshem: That's better than nothing I guess :-)

Comment: I would recommend digging around the IUCN Red List (iucnredlist.org) and birdlife.org websites.

Comment: I take it you've read the wikipedia article and followed the appropriate bibliographic references, for example http://australianmuseum.net.au/Emu ?

Comment: @BarryCarter: Yes, this page does not contain any history nor population information unfortunately.

Comment: Oh, I meant actually contacting someone (ie, the curator) at australianmuseum.net.au. If these stats exist, that's a good starting point to find them.

Answer (score 3):

There are 9 different types of emu whose populations range from common to extinct.  The [Grey Emu](http://www.iucnredlist.org/details/22715475/0) is prevalent, while the [Kangaroo Island Emu](http://www.iucnredlist.org/details/22724449/0) is extinct.

If you want general populations of emu in Australia, try [Birdata](http://birdata.com.au/), which shows populations of Australian birds by location and time, and allows you to download custom datasets.  Here's the link for [emus](http://birdata.com.au/maps.vm?lat=-21.1&lon=148.8&scale=895945&species=834).  Many other [sites](http://www.environment.nsw.gov.au/threatenedspeciesapp/profileData.aspx?id=10250&cmaName=Northern%20Rivers) simply state that the emu is not endangered.

For a truly interesting read on the Great Emu War, check out this [Scientific American article](http://blogs.scientificamerican.com/running-ponies/2014/08/04/the-great-emu-war-in-which-some-large-flightless-birds-unwittingly-foiled-the-australian-army/).

Comment: Interesting links! They don't contain historical data though, right?